# How can i get a node name on firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a menu for a restaurant, first of all I want to know if this structure is correct.

[image]

```
 "menu" : {
    "Steak taco" : {
      "Description" : "Roasted steak with chipotle sauce taco.",
      "Price" : 5
    }
  }
```

if its not, how can i improve it.
Second, i want to retrive child menu name. for example, i want to get Steak taco name, the description and price

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference refNom = ref.child("Locales");

final DatabaseReference refNom = ref.child("Locales");
            refNom.orderByChild("Nombre").equalTo(nombreLocal/*i'm getting this from a getExtra*/).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    lista.removeAll(lista);
    for (DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

    String nomPlatillo = ds1.child("menu").getKey();
    String descPlatillo = ds1.child("menu")./*dish_name.child*/child("Description").getValue(String.class);
    double precio = ds1.child("menu")./*dish_name.child*/child("price").getValue(double.class);
    datosMenu menu = new datosMenu(nomPlatillo,descPlatillo,precio);
    lista.add(menu);
}
```

This is my loop:

Comment: Please share how you get `dataSnapshot` from the database, since the proper solution depends on that.

Comment: Now it's edited frank

Answer (score 1):

Since menu will have lot of items, I guess it would be better if you can create like array of items

```
{
  "menu": [
    {
      "item": "Steak taco",
      "desc": "",
      "price": "5",
      "image_url": ""
    },{
      "item": "pizza",
      "desc": "",
      "price": "4",
      "image_url": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

This way it would be easy to iteratively parse.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a child. Between your `menu` node and the `Description` key there is one more step in the tree hierarchy, `Steak taco`. So to solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
String descPlatillo = ds1.child("menu")./*dish_name.child*/child("Description").getValue(String.class);
double precio = ds1.child("menu")./*dish_name.child*/child("price").getValue(double.class);
```

to

```
String descPlatillo = ds1.child("menu").child("Steak taco").getValue(String.class);
double precio = ds1.child("menu").child("Steak taco").getValue(Double.class);
```

Please also note that is have used `getValue(Double.class)` and not `getValue(double.class)`.

Comment: i know that, but the name of that child will be different, because i will be putting different dishes, and the name will be change, so i want to get the name of that node (in this example Taco Steak), with their respective descriptions and price..

Comment: In this case you should use `.child(yourVariable)` instead of `.child("Steak taco")`. In which `yourVariable` holds whatever you need to create the reference. You cannot leave it empty.

Comment: Yeah but, the app doesn't know the names of the dishes, so i can't create a variable for every name of a dish, what i want it's to get the name of that dish/node, dinamically, because the names will be different

Comment: In this case you need to hold the value of that dish in a variable when creating that particular dish. In this way you'll be able to use it later in your reference, right?

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?

Comment: well, the app it's just for presentation, so i created predefiend objects to put into the menu, i wasn't able to think about a way to get the data from firebase.